# Emulator is not being showed in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have Android Studio 3.4, my emulator is API 5.1.

It is created properly but its screen is not being shown.

Even after I run my code on that emulator, the screen of the emulator is not shown. I can't see the output of the code.

Comment: What happens when you open the emulator from android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the app on emulator other than API Level 5.1?

Comment: my app is 4.0 or something around, it is running properly but the display is not shown.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of emulator after running the app?

Comment: the link of the screenshot is given in the ans, pls check it

Answer (score 0):

[the image is given,the app has  run properly,but the screen of the e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Fwb.png)